# Reload page when a certain width is passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, window, width

I want the page to reload only if the browser window goes above or below 768px.
This was my attempt which failed.

```
if ($(window.width() > "769") {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < "769") {
            location.reload();
        }
    });

}
elseif($(window.width() < "769") {

    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() > "769") {
            location.reload();
        }
    });

}
```

Im sures theres a really simple way of doing this.

Comment: Why?? Could you explain why you are asking for such functionality? Maybe there is an option you are overlooking for this purpose.

Comment: Agreed above. The `resize` function gets triggered instantaneously as the window size changes. So when a user holds the window corner and starts resizing it the page will be reloaded over and over again until he leaves the mouse button (or stops resizing), which will probably result in annoyance.

Comment: Im making a responsive site and need to do some link rewriting for the mobile version under a certain width. And have the links revert back to normal over a certain width. Its not essential but i wanted to use a refresh incase people try playing with just resizing browser width. Im link rewriting in a strange way which would require a refresh of page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### *[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YFTht/2/)*

The proof that the page is reloaded is (the wait icon in the tab :D ) the Math random that generates a random number (in the demo.)

```
var ww = $(window).width();
var limit = 769;

function refresh() {
   ww = $(window).width();
   var w =  ww<limit ? (location.reload(true)) :  ( ww>limit ? (location.reload(true)) : ww=limit );
}

var tOut;
$(window).resize(function() {
    var resW = $(window).width();
    clearTimeout(tOut);
    if ( (ww>limit && resW<limit) || (ww<limit && resW>limit) ) {        
        tOut = setTimeout(refresh, 100);
    }
});
```

The timeout function will help on window resize to wait 100ms before calling the `refresh` function.
You can increase the timeout value to improve usability.

Comment: This works great thanks but I dont quite understand what you did. How did you become such a ninja?

Comment: Do you think this will cause any slowdown used on a website?

Comment: @chris Thank you Chris! haha :) No! this will not slow down your page. You can have lots of timeouts and intervals on your page, if they are gently handled, timed or synchronized all will be fine. In this case we pass on the resize ev. - `if` statement - a cached val of window.width, and the timeouted `refresh function` is triggered only after that check, and after a 100ms delay. If you wisely increase that value you will only make the effect better and less 'shocky' for a User Experience

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Can I do the same with multiple limit not just 769, Thanks :)

Comment: @jim how you mean 'multiple' please clarify

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I meant the page reload when the browser resize between 300 & 769 & 1024, Your code now just reload when the page passing size width 769 px, I want do the same with 3 different sizes

Answer (score 3):

There are probably other and much better ways of doing what you **really** need, but:

```
if ($(window.width() > "769"){
```

Should be:

```
if ($(window).width() > 769){
```

**Full code:**

```
var width = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (width > 769 && $(window).width() < 769) {
        location.reload();
    }
    else if (width < 769 && $(window).width() > 769) {
        location.reload();
    }
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q4Udy/1/embedded/result/)

It could be made with one if statement, but I preferred splitting it into two so it'll be easier to follow.

Comment: Let it go to hell. Your turn ;)

Comment: @VisioN. You shouldn't have deleted your answer, they accept your's in the end... `:)`

Comment: This looks promising but doesnt work yet. Will test it out a bit more and write back.

Comment: ^^^ LMAO :D You also have all chances :)

Comment: @chris. I added a demo, check the console.

Comment: @VisioN. Are you sure you don't won't to undelete it? `:)` it might be too late in couple of minutes. I added a demo... **LOL**

Comment: The console shows the current width but the page never reloads?

Comment: @gdoron I knew it was a bad idea. I had no chances against `setTimeout` :)

Comment: @chris. I updated the demo to make it even clearer, but **it works!** what problem are you facing?

Comment: Now is starts to reload @ a certain width but hangs... and never actual loads... not sure why. I up-voted your response and appreciate the time but I had to accept the other answer because it just worked.

Comment: Hello @gdoron, I need the same solution but with 3 break points to reload not just 769 but I need 300 & 769 & 1024, I tried to modified the code by myself but didn't work out for me, can I get any help??, And Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Hi @Jim, I will help if I'll know the answer. Can you post a http://jsfiddle.net so I can review your code? anyway you can ask a new question with your specific situation and problem to get help from the community. Waiting to hear from you.

Comment: @gdoron I did ask a new one right here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393793/reload-page-when-window-passing-certain-multiple-widths , Thank you :)