# Reload page when window passing certain multiple widths

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the page reload only if the browser window passing width 300px or 769px or 1024px

There is a similar question to my request (http://goo.gl/46jjzH) but the only problem with the approved answer is that the page reload after passing just 769px, I need to do the same with 3 different sizes 300px or 769px or 1024px not just 769px.

The two codes that works only with one certain width from http://goo.gl/46jjzH

First code by @Roko C. Buljan

```
var ww = $(window).width();
var limit = 769;

function refresh() {
   ww = $(window).width();
   var w =  ww<limit ? (location.reload(true)) :  ( ww>limit ? (location.reload(true)) : ww=limit );
}

var tOut;
$(window).resize(function() {
    var resW = $(window).width();
    clearTimeout(tOut);
    if ( (ww>limit && resW<limit) || (ww<limit && resW>limit) ) {        
        tOut = setTimeout(refresh, 100);
    }
});
```

And the second code by @gdoron

```
var width = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (width > 769 && $(window).width() < 769) {
        location.reload();
    }
    else if (width < 769 && $(window).width() > 769) {
        location.reload();
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Going with the second code sample, you can check for the alternate conditions using an `or` operator.

```
var prevWidth = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function() {
    var currentWidth = $(window).width();

    if (
        (prevWidth > 769 && currentWidth  < 769) 
        || (prevWidth > 300 currentWidth  < 300)
        || (prevWidth > 1024 currentWidth  < 1024)  
    )

    {
        location.reload();
    }

});​
```